# technical term for this phenomenon: minor adjustments to a notebook's LED-LCD screen angle result in major legibility issues

Tags: led, terminology, touchscreen

Perhaps a bit of background will help you to understand the question I'm trying to formulate. I have no engineering background but would like to read more about this LED-LCD phenomenon though I don't know what it is called.

I had an older generation Chromebook made by manufacturer A, one of its keys broke, and the cost of a keyboard repair was 50% of the cost of buying a new Chromebook made by manufacturer B. So I bought B's model. When I started to use the new device with a familiar application(e.g. an online chess program) I noticed that very minor adjustments to the angle of the screen would put my white chess pieces  in a bright glare; they appeared "washed out" while black's pieces appeared to be in a gloom, so that they were barely distinguishable from the dark border area surrounding the board.

This artefact wasn't from ambient light reflecting off the screen  but from the **angle of the light emanating from the "anti-glare" LED-LCD display.**

I assume there's a technical term for the optimal viewing angle range of a LED?

Comment: Maybe it just has a cheap display with narrow viewing angle?

Comment: I think it's "viewing angle".  I could hit the web and verify this, but I'm going to leave that as an exercise for someone else.

Comment: BTW, some high-end laptops have intentionally made viewing angle, *both* vertical and horizontal, *very* narrow to help obscure the screen for someone looking over the user's shoulder.

Comment: Yeah, [viewing angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_angle)

Comment: It's the vertical viewing angle here.  When the center of the board was clearly visible, black's first row was in deep shadow.